# Wave-particle duality - particles as a special case of waves?

Tags: wave-particle-duality

This may be an incredibly dumb question, but I'm asking it anyway.

**What is wrong in thinking that particles are just waves with amplitude zero?**

Comment: The problem with thinking of particles as amplitude-zero waves is pretty much the same as the problem with thinking of a dog's tail as a fifth leg.  Calling a tail a leg doesn't make it one.

Comment: The wave-particle duality is an outdated historical concept from the beginnings of quantum theory. Quantum objects are described by rays in a Hilbert space, not by being "waves" or "particles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Born interpretation, the probability of finding a particle near a point $x$ is $|\psi(x)|^2$.  If $\psi(x) = 0$, then the probability of finding the particle is zero for all locations, which means that the particle doesn't exist.

**EDIT:**  The "amplitude" of a general wave-function isn't really well-defined, but roughly speaking it tells us "how big" the wavefunction is.  In other words, we could take a wavefunction over all of space and multiply it by a constant $A$ to get the same wavefunction, just with higher/lower "peaks" and deeper/shallower "valleys".  For example, compare the functions $\psi(x) = \cos x$ and $\psi(x) = 2 \cos x$.  This is, I think, the notion of "amplitude" that most people are familiar with.

The thing about wavefunctions, though, is that their amplitude is fixed by the Born interpretation mentioned above.  In particular, the probability that we find the particle *somewhere*—anywhere—must be equal to 1.  This means that we must have
$$
\int_\text{all space} |\psi(x)|^2 dx = 1.
$$
If we take this wavefunction and change its amplitude, we would get
$$
\int_\text{all space} |A \psi(x)|^2 dx = |A|^2 \int_\text{all space} |\psi(x)|^2 dx = |A|^2
$$
and so the probability of the particle's existence would be something other than 1.  In particular, if $A = 0$, then the probability of the particle being found would be zero;  this is the point I was trying to make above.

Now, what I think you're trying to get at is something like the following:  in classical mechanics, we know the particle's position exactly.  This means that there a probability of 1 to find the particle at one specific location $x = x_0$, and *zero* probability to find it everywhere else.  In particular, this means that $\psi(x) = 0$ for $x \neq x_0$; but since we must have the square-integral of $\psi$ equal to one (as above), this means that $\psi(x_0)$ must be infinite.  Physicists use the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) to model such situations;  in this case, we would have $|\psi(x)|^2 = \delta(x - x_0)$.  But you can't really say that this function has "zero amplitude", since its maximum value is, well, infinite.

(I'm running roughshod over a lot of precise mathematics in my description of the $\delta$-function, by the way.  Click through to the Wikipedia article to see how it's defined more rigorously.)

Comment: Is setting the wavefunction to zero equivalent to setting its amplitude to zero? Please, elaborate on that part.

Comment: @user132181:  in any inner product space, the only vector of length zero is the zero vector.  This is part of the definition of an inner product.